# Proper handling of NSUbiquityKeyValueStore updates across devices?

Tags: objective-c, ios, icloud, nsubiquitouskeyvaluestore

My app stores a single key-value pair in iCloud using NSUbiquityKeyValueStore, an array of objects.  The entire array is saved to iCloud when a change is made to any object in the array.  This works great as long as each device has an opportunity to pull down the latest update before a change is made locally.  Otherwise the local change can get pushed up to iCloud before other devices' latest updates have been pulled down, and those updates get lost across all devices.  Is this my app's shortcoming or iCloud's shortcoming, and how can I prevent this scenario from occurring?

Answer (score 2):

*Otherwise the local change can get pushed up to iCloud before other devices' latest updates have been pulled down*

I ran into a similar issue this week with a project I'm working on.  I just made sure that I didn't push anything up to the iCloud server until I received my first update from iCloud.   Also, FWIW, I  set a fake key-value pair right after initialization so that it updates immediately.

HackyStack's idea of a local flag is also a good solution; if a change comes in you can ask the user if they want to use it or not.  (sorta like how Kindle asks if you want to update to the latest page).

Comment: This sounds good if the only reconciliation takes place at app initialization.  In my scenario reconciliations can take place any time.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand the exact issue, but I believe the answer is either a category on NSObject (where you could have a "version" property) to check the "version" of the object OR you need another key-value pair to store on iCloud for "version" that can be compared to one stored locally on the device (lastUpdateVersion) to know where you stand.  If you could give me an exact real world example of your problem I could answer better...  It could be that you don't even need a "version" but rather a flag (BOOL).

Comment: Thanks for responding.  The array in question holds color palette objects, which can be added, deleted or their individual colors modified.  If, for example, several palettes are added on an iPad, and shortly thereafter a palette is modified on an iPhone before the iPad's added palettes are retrieved from iCloud, the iPhone pushes its version of the color palettes array--now with the modified palette but lacking the iPad's new palettes--and propagated to the iPad (and any other device) resulting in a loss of the added palettes.

Comment: So can't you just set a local flag noting that you have local changes and then add logic not to update until those are reconciled?  This is a common "sequencing" problem that I think you could solve with some simple logic unless I'm just totally missing something...

Comment: But how do I even know that there are changes yet to be reconciled?  The scenario where another device's changes are pending is the same as the scenario where there aren't.

Answer (score 0):

You should read the documentation for -[NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore synchronize].  It gives you a decent idea of when to use it and what its limits are.  In particular, pay attention to the fact that it makes no promises on when it actually synchronises the data, and implies that updates are uploaded to iCloud only a couple of times at a minute, at most (and that may apply to the device as a whole, not just your app).

The key-value storage mechanism is intended to be very simple and used only for non-essential data, typically configuration information about your app.  You shouldn't store user data in it, basically, or anything that resembles it.  For that kind of data, use the file-based iCloud APIs.  They're more complicated, but with them you have more insight into the sync state of your data, and most importantly you can be notified of conflicts and provide your own merge handler.

Answer (score 0):

> Is this my app's shortcoming or iCloud's shortcoming, and how can I prevent this scenario from occurring?

This is an app shortcoming and expected behaviour from iCloud. You can account for this in various ways, but in general, this won't be easy. Especially with >2 devices, there are  scenarios where conflicting changes will never be presented to a device to do resolution, as generally speaking the iCloud behaviour is "last change wins" (see my longer description below). Some thoughts:

- instead of using an array of objects, use individual keys for each object. Obviously this depends on the semantics of your app, but if the objects are essentially independent, then this generally will give your app the behaviour it expects
- if all the items are interlinked, then you will have to do your own conflict resolution. The best way to do this will depend heavily on your app + data semantics. E.g. maybe you could add a timestamp to your array, or to some objects in the array. You could use new key names for every save so that all devices eventually get all keys and can resolve conflicts (obviously this could chew through storage quickly!). Resolving conflicts might not be worth doing depending what you're already storing locally to help with this

### Background

I recently had reason to research the topic of `NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore` change conflicts in some (tedious) depth. I found some information in two old WWDC videos that expand on current Apple documentation, specifically WWDC11 Adopting iCloud Storage, part 1 ([currently available here](http://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/ios/ios_5_tech_talk_world_tou/adopting_icloud_storage__part_1.mov), found via [here](https://gist.github.com/IsaacXen/874c59aec92a13f30728aecdabb9ea80#file-wwdc2011)) at locations 17:38 and subsequently (e.g. 19:27). Another is a WWDC12 iCloud Storage Overview talk ([here](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2012__hd/session_209__icloud_storage_overview.mov) originally via [here](https://mackuba.eu/notes/wwdc12/icloud-storage-overview/)) at 6:30 and 10:55. I subsequently verified the behaviour described below by running two devices, an iPhone 8 running iOS 15.2 and an iPad Air 2 running iOS 12.4 with a test program and lots of console logging in Xcode. What follows is my best guess of the intended behaviour and mechanism for conflict resolution.

### Summary

When an individual key is saved by a device using `NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore.default.set(value, forKey: key)`, a hidden `timestamp` is included with the key with the device time of that call. If/when the operating system syncs with the iCloud replica of the key value store, it examines the `timestamp`s for each key and, if the iCloud `timestamp` is earlier in time, it saves the new key value and `timestamp` into the iCloud key value store. If the key value is saved, devices that are currently registered and online to receive notifications will be notified that this key has changed and can fetch the new value if they wish. If iCloud does NOT save the key value, NO notification will happen on any device, and the change is simply dropped.

### Notes

- If all devices on this iCloud account are online while in use *(caveat low power mode, poor internet connection etc.)*, the result is generally exactly what you want: the app makes a change, it is saved in iCloud, it propagates to other devices. Notifications happen as expected, if a device has registered for them.
- If device A saves a `value` while it is offline, and another device B later saves a `value` while it is online, then device A goes online, the change from device A is ignored, as iCloud now has a newer `value` with a later `timestamp`. B will never be notified of A's change. However, if A has registered for changes, A *will* get notified of the newer B `value` and can then decide if it should re-submit its value.
- Because of this "last in wins" behaviour, multiple values that belong together should thus be saved together as a dictionary or array, as suggested in various Apple docs and talks.
- Values that don't interact should be saved as individual keys - thus allowing most recent changes from multiple devices to successfully intermingle.
- There is no automated way to test these behaviours. Back in Xcode 9 days, it was possible to UI script two simulators to verify sync worked as expected, but that hasn't worked in a while, which leaves manual testing as a poor and tedious substitute.
- `NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore` is a great solution for many scenarios beyond simple app settings. Personally, I'd like to see more keys (e.g. 10k instead of 1k), but the general ease of setup and separated storage from a customer's iCloud quota is generally a joy.

There's no perfect solution in a real world environment where devices are not always reliably connected. Indeed, some customers may intentionally keep, say, an older iPad, mostly offline to save battery between intermittent usage. If you can keep your synced data in small discrete units and save it one value per key, sync will generally work as expected.